# How to convert double digit string to int in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

In my project, I have a table that represents a schedule. In first column I have info about time (hours:minutes)[image]

I'm trying to extract the text from one cell and split it into hours and minutes, because I'll use them to create a Date object. However when I try to `parseInt(09)` it returns NaN. I even added the radix 10, but that didn't work too.

Can you help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: `parseInt(09)` tries to parse an octal 9, which doesn't exist. This shouldn't be a problem in your code, since the value you're parsing is a string already. `parseInt` is purposed to be used with strings, hence `parseInt('09', 10)` would give you the correct result. Reading [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) is always usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split`:

```js
var time = "17:30";
var hours = time.split(":")[0];
var minutes = time.split(":")[1];
console.log("hours:   " + hours);
console.log("minutes: " + minutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey your example should work, but seems like you don't pass a string to parseInt, I belive that you have those times as string which you can parse like this

```js
const time = "10:30"
const split = time.split(":")

const hours = parseInt(split[0], 10)
const minutes = parseInt(split[1], 10)

console.log(hours, minutes)
```

Answer (score 0):

use code :

```
var time = "13:30";
var hours = time.split(":")[0];
var minutes = time.split(":")[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `split`, `map` and `Bit shifting`.

```js
const timeStr = "09:30";
const [hour, min] = timeStr.split(':').map(item => item >> 0);
console.log(hour, min);
```

The code `item => item >> 0` means it takes the split value and it executes a zero bit right shifting returns a 32 bit number.